# CSS round corners images in IE7?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, rounded-corners

It is possible to do in CSS rounded corners to images working in IE 7? I have div with rounded corners and inside is

CODE:

CSS:

```
.box2 {

width: 150px;
height: 150px;
margin: 0 auto 35px auto;
padding: 30px;
color: #fff;
font-weight: bold;
border: 5px solid #35b70e;
border-radius:200px; 
overflow:hidden;
behavior:url(border-radius.htc);

}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="box2">
<img class="super" alt="" src="https://www.google.pl/images/srpr/logo4w.png"></img></a>
</div>
```

Div have rounded corners but image extends outside the div ;/

SCREEN:
http://prntscr.com/14zx09

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

Hey Jakub you can use `PIE.htc` for your desired result...

> PIE makes Internet Explorer 6-9 capable of rendering several of the
>   most useful CSS3 decoration features.....

[Read more about PIE.HTC](http://css3pie.com/)

Comment: The url what you given is not working in IE8,not tested in other version.